# What are the effects of increasing hard and soft limits for ldap user

Tags: limit, ulimit, openldap

I've been having some instability issues with my LDAP server. I have ~2000 machines connecting to it.  Using `netstat -pant | grep slapd`, I can typically see 1500+ connections from the clients to the server at any given moment.  But every so often, the connection count drops to zero. At that point the clients start having problems with jobs that rely on LDAP.  I have to restart slapd on the LDAP server to get it to start accepting connections again.  Sometime I have to restart the ldap daemon on the clients too.

I've been told by a vendor that I need to increase the hard and soft nofile limits for the LDAP user so that it can accept more connections. 
Current settings:

```
ldap@myldapserver:~> ulimit -Hn
8192
ldap@myldapserver:~> ulimit -Sn
4500
```

The vendor suggests 65000 hard and 16000 soft.

```
ldap    soft    nofile  16000
ldap    hard    nofile  65000
```

This seems like a pretty dramatic increase and I can't help but wonder if this will have any adverse effects on the server. The LDAP server is a single purpose server. Should I be worried?

Comment: Did you try it, and does it solve the issue? It sounds like there's more going on, as if you were hitting the `nofile` limit, your connection count should peak and hold, not drop to 0.

Comment: I can't try it in the production environment and the test environment doesn't have anywhere near the same number of clients.

Comment: You can check if this is really the issue by doing `ls -1 /proc/$(pidof slapd)/fd | wc -l`. The number you get back should be around 4500 if you're truly hitting the `nofile` limit.

Comment: This is one of those things that you'll have to likely either try in production or concoct a test in development that will allow you throw that many clients at the server while you test the efficacy of the potential fix.

Comment: In my experience, it's not uncommon to have very conservative ulimit default values. If it makes you feel any better, here are some for Oracle DBs, as a totally arbitrary example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm

Answer (score 1):

These limits set how many files a process may have opened at a time. 
The "hard" limit is absolute, no process is allowed to go over this limit. 
The "soft" limit can be changed by the process at any time. This is only useful if the process cooperates well, but security-wise it won't help you. That is why you have a hard limit.

I am not sure about the limits suggested by the vendor, but after a Google search I found the MongoDB documentation recommending setting the limit to 64000.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/